# I need to disable subject dropdown selection in contact form Prestashop 1.7

Tags: contact-form, prestashop-1.7, dropdownbox

Im workin on a page i need to remove selection subject drop down and instead people writes the subject down

i already tried with this....

```
                         <input 
                         "hidden" 
                         class="form-control" 
                         name="id_contact" 
                         value="{$contact_elt.id_contact}">

                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, contact form require a contact id for the subject.

You can add more subject in Shop Parameters -> Contact.

Regards

Comment: its not possible to write the subject down instead of clickin on drop down.... the thing its that we only have one subject so theres no point to have a drop down